# GLib-GIO-Message: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend. Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications

Tags: python, linux, opencv, ubuntu

I am working on python project with opencv on Ubuntu OS

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("LillyBellea.png", 1)
img = cv2.imwrite("LillyBellea.jpeg", img)
cv2.imshow("original", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

when i am running this program then i am getting error

```
GLib-GIO-Message: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend.  Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications.
```

can any one please help here,
I have follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/558446/my-dconf-gsettings-installation-is-broken-how-can-i-fix-it-without-ubuntu-reins) answer but its not working for me

Answer (score 62, accepted):

This fixed the issue for me:

```
export GIO_EXTRA_MODULES=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/
```

See: https://github.com/conda-forge/glib-feedstock/issues/19 for more info.

Comment: I would like to add that to actually solve this problem, you need to add this to your local bashrc, otherwise, every time you open a terminal, the export is gone.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt install dconf-gsettings-backend:i386
```

Fixed it for me. (Note: in my case I was running x86 app on x64 system.)